# How can get selected Radio Button from Radio Group from a fragment inside activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-radiogroup

im new in android, i cant get the logic to get selected value from radiogroup on a fragment inside an activity.
I Wanna make a simple questioner for my class.

Here is my java

```
public class Frag3_Kepentingan extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view_frag3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_frag3_kepentingan, container, false);
    return view_frag3;
```

I already give id for each radio button & radio group.
Here is my xml_Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp">

        <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/grup31"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/grup31A1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/grup31A2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/grup31A3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

       </RadioGroup>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSimpanGrup3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Simpan" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for your sharing.

Comment: create get and set method for radio check/unchecked in fragment, now access those method in activity!

Answer (score 0):

```
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


            switch (checkedId)
            {

                //your desire code
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A `RadioGroup` layout should look like this

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/myRadioGroup"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbMale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Male"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbFemale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Female"
        android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

  </RadioGroup>
```

Initialise the `RadioButtons` in your Fragemnt

```
RadioButton rMale = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rbMale);
RadioButton rFemale = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rbFemale);
```

Get Value from `RadioButton` if checked or un-checked

```
 String userGender= "";
                if (rMale.isChecked()) {
                    userGender = "male";
                } else if (rFemale.isChecked()) {
                    userGender = "female";
                }
```